# ruby furigana + increased ruby size + verse environment = unwanted whitespace

Tags: spacing, xetex, cjk, verse, xecjk

I'm trying to typeset song lyrics in Japanese.  I want the words to be accompanied by *furigana* glosses, as provided by the `ruby` package.  But the default ruby size is too small, so I increased it as per documentation:

```
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.5} % default: 0.4
```

I then use the `verse` environment to typeset songs:

```
% [⋮]

\begin{verse}
世界に\\
\ruby{誕生}{たんじょう}\\
\ruby{瞬間}{しゅんかん}\\
誕生\\
その\ruby{繰}{く}り\ruby{返}{かえ}し
\endf{verse}
```

[(Sample document here)](http://namakajiri.net/misc/ruby-test.tex)

However, this specific combination—`ruby` + `verse` + larger `\rubysize`—somehow generates horizontal spacing on the start of the line, pushing the base (non-ruby) characters to the right.  Notice how the base characters below are not left-aligned properly on lines 2 and 3:

[image: ruby package spacing issue at start of line]

How do I keep the Japanese characters left-aligned even when they have *furigana* glosses?

I'm using XeTeX, xeCJK, the ruby package, `verse`, Hiragino Mincho Pro, and TeX Live 2015.

Comment: please make that a complete document that produces the image, so we can run it.

Comment: Also because [I'm not getting your unwanted space](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BCFY7.png) (so it's probably a conflict with something else in your code).

Comment: Added sample minimal document, in the process of which I found that the problem only appears if 1) I increase \rubysize, and also 2) in the `verse` environment.  I should have done this from the beginning; sorry.

Comment: @leoboiko Post that as an answer, it might be useful in the future.

Comment: The question still lacks a full MWE and based on the comments I'm not sure quite what we are expected to say.

Comment: Is the sample document I provided (the "Sample document here" link) not adequate?

Comment: I tried rewording the question; is it clearer now?

Comment: @leoboiko Please put the complete document into this post, instead of at a link which may 1) contain unknown software, so people may be reluctant to visit or 2) be removed from the internet at any time, rendering this post meaningless for future visitors :-)